# Do we need the [mixing] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

It doesn't even have a description (it's still in search of one).
Actual usage seems to be a mixture (sic) of questions about programming using mixed languages, and mixing paint.

Comment: Also a fair amount of mixing sounds. Those might be changed to [audio-mixing]...if that tag existed. Doesn't seem to at the moment, so I'm not sure if it's needed.

Comment: The "mixed languages" usage seems to be plain wrong, though.

Comment: Maybe related to [[tag:mixture]]? Its tag wiki says its a stats thing.

Comment: _"We are experts in [mixing] useless tags"_